# Visual Studio 2015 reporting services missing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014

I have just installed SQL server 2014 developer on my home computer running windows 8.1. To create reports I installed Visual studio 2015 with the business intelligence templates. when I attempted to create a report, reporting services was missing from the templates the only template available was integration services. How can I get that template?

Answer (score 0):

The Report Designer is part of the Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools.

You can add it using the Visual Studio setup (Programs and Features > Visual Studio 2015 > Change)